# Bluebird's Promise.map() not working with Mongoose when plugged into mongoose.Promise

Tags: mongoose, bluebird

I am currently working with Mongoose and Bluebird as a plugged in Promise library.
Following mongoose docs, I have done the following:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.Promise = require('bluebird');

// Some function making use of Bluebird's Promise.map()
function someFn() {
    return Promise.map([
        someModel.findById(someId).exec(),
        someOtherModel.findById(someOtherId).exec()
    ], mapperFn)
        .then(function() {})
        .catch(function() {});
}
```

As you can see, I am trying to use bluebird's `Promise.map()` in my code, but I keep getting the following error:

```
TypeError: Promise.map is not a function
```

Then I tried by requiring bluebird and setting it to a new `var Promise`, like this

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Promise = require('bluebird');

// Some function making use of Bluebird's Promise.map()
function someFn() {
    return Promise.map([
        someMode.findById(someId).exec(),
        someOtherModel.findById(someOtherId).exec()
    ], mapperFn)
        .then(function() {})
        .catch(function() {});
}
```

This worked, but does not seem to be the right way to approach this issue. I do not know if this might cause any conflicts with other variables in the mongoose code.

Any suggestions to make this work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to use `Promise.map()`, you need to define `Promise` to be Bluebird's object, not just the regular ES6 `Promise`.  You would do that like this:

```
let Promise = require('bluebird');
mongoose.Promise = Promise;
```

Or, you could even just do this:

```
let Promise = mongoose.Promise = require('bluebird');
```

As it was, you were trying to do `Promise.map()` with the regular ES6 version of `Promise`.

---

Your second approach was properly defining `Promise` to be Bluebird's library and that's why `Promise.map()` worked, but you were not using Bluebird's promises with mongoose which will work in some cases because of promise interoperability between different types of promises as long as you only use `.then()` on the promises that come back from mongoose and nothing special like the myriad of Bluebird additional methods.

Comment: Interesting, it also worked with `sequelize`:  `let Promise = sequelize.Promise = require('bluebird');`

Answer (score 0):

The error you obtained was caused by defining `mongoose.Promise` rather than `Promise`, and then using `Promise`, a variable that doesn't exist in that scope.

The second approach doesn't seem to be modifying anything within `mongoose` whatsoever. However just to be sure it would be interesting to see how `promiseArray` is defined.

Then, I do not recommend passing `undefined` as handlers for `then` and `catch`.

Comment: Let me edit it to show a more accurate picture of what I'm doing.

Comment: By changing `mongoose.Promise` to `Promise` as you suggested, I got it working. Now, my question is, will this apply bluebird to the rest of Mongoose's promises? Better said, will this override mongoose's default mpromise?

Comment: According to the mongoose documentation, mongoose uses Promises/A+ compliant promises. Meaning that they should be able to interoperate with bluebird, which are also implement the Promises/A+ standard.

Following your second approach you are not altering mongoose in any way.

Now, it is highly recommended that if you want to go with bluebird, you still do the `mongoose.Promise = require('bluebird')` step.